# Compute total distance from an ordering of a path

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have a distance matrix and a data.frame of orderings that I want to compute the total distances for each ordering (row).

distance matrix (generated by `as.matrix(dist(x, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE))`):

```
               FOV5.1.T4.C1 FOV5.1.T4.C1.1 FOV5.1.T4.C2 FOV5.1.T4.C2.1
FOV5.1.T4.C1      0.0000000     11.5454430    0.3431676     13.2814257
FOV5.1.T4.C1.1   11.5454430      0.0000000   11.5625031      2.8374444
FOV5.1.T4.C2      0.3431676     11.5625031    0.0000000     13.2407547
FOV5.1.T4.C2.1   13.2814257      2.8374444   13.2407547      0.0000000
```

ordering (generated by `expand.grid()`):

```
            Var1           Var2
1   FOV5.1.T4.C2   FOV5.1.T4.C1
2 FOV5.1.T4.C2.1   FOV5.1.T4.C1
3   FOV5.1.T4.C2 FOV5.1.T4.C1.1
4 FOV5.1.T4.C2.1 FOV5.1.T4.C1.1
```

Expected Output:

```
            Var1           Var2          Dist
1   FOV5.1.T4.C2   FOV5.1.T4.C1      0.3431676
2 FOV5.1.T4.C2.1   FOV5.1.T4.C1     13.2814257
3   FOV5.1.T4.C2 FOV5.1.T4.C1.1       ...
4 FOV5.1.T4.C2.1 FOV5.1.T4.C1.1       ...
```

I would like a total distance column appended to the end of the ordering data frame that would give the total distance from `Var1` to `VarN`.

**EDIT**: The ultimate goal is to generalize this problem for many orderings (rows) and elements (columns) of the ordering data frame. For example:

distance matrix:

```
                FOV10.5.T1.C1 FOV10.5.T1.C1.1 FOV10.5.T6.C1 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1 FOV10.5.T7.C2 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1 FOV10.5.T7.C4 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1
FOV10.5.T1.C1        0.000000        9.259314      9.525777        4.920990      8.520076        3.246356     10.429007       12.771907
FOV10.5.T1.C1.1      9.259314        0.000000      2.903446        6.485444      2.604540        6.943048      2.962850       12.658076
FOV10.5.T6.C1        9.525777        2.903446      0.000000        8.185294      1.095356        8.058659      5.763981        9.949294
FOV10.5.T6.C1.1      4.920990        6.485444      8.185294        0.000000      7.233955        1.724583      6.384782       15.156368
FOV10.5.T7.C2        8.520076        2.604540      1.095356        7.233955      0.000000        7.054426      5.528189       10.060419
FOV10.5.T7.C2.1      3.246356        6.943048      8.058659        1.724583      7.054426        0.000000      7.488958       13.938926
FOV10.5.T7.C4       10.429007        2.962850      5.763981        6.384782      5.528189        7.488958      0.000000       15.570799
FOV10.5.T7.C4.1     12.771907       12.658076      9.949294       15.156368     10.060419       13.938926     15.570799        0.000000
```

ordering:

```
              Var1            Var2            Var3            Var4   Dist
1    FOV10.5.T1.C1   FOV10.5.T7.C4   FOV10.5.T7.C2   FOV10.5.T6.C1   sum(Var1 --> Var2, Var2 --> Var3, Var3 --> Var4)
2  FOV10.5.T1.C1.1   FOV10.5.T7.C4   FOV10.5.T7.C2   FOV10.5.T6.C1   ...
3    FOV10.5.T1.C1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1   FOV10.5.T7.C2   FOV10.5.T6.C1   ...
4  FOV10.5.T1.C1.1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1   FOV10.5.T7.C2   FOV10.5.T6.C1   ...
5    FOV10.5.T1.C1   FOV10.5.T7.C4 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1   FOV10.5.T6.C1
6  FOV10.5.T1.C1.1   FOV10.5.T7.C4 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1   FOV10.5.T6.C1
7    FOV10.5.T1.C1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1   FOV10.5.T6.C1
8  FOV10.5.T1.C1.1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1   FOV10.5.T6.C1
9    FOV10.5.T1.C1   FOV10.5.T7.C4   FOV10.5.T7.C2 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
10 FOV10.5.T1.C1.1   FOV10.5.T7.C4   FOV10.5.T7.C2 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
11   FOV10.5.T1.C1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1   FOV10.5.T7.C2 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
12 FOV10.5.T1.C1.1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1   FOV10.5.T7.C2 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
13   FOV10.5.T1.C1   FOV10.5.T7.C4 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
14 FOV10.5.T1.C1.1   FOV10.5.T7.C4 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
15   FOV10.5.T1.C1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
16 FOV10.5.T1.C1.1 FOV10.5.T7.C4.1 FOV10.5.T7.C2.1 FOV10.5.T6.C1.1
```

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: Added expected output to original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)

points <- replicate(5, sample(1:100, 2, T)) %>% 
            `colnames<-`(letters[1:5]) 

dists <-  points %>% 
            t %>% 
            dist %>% 
            as.matrix %>% 
            melt(value.name = 'dist') %>% 
            mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)

paths <- replicate(5, sample(colnames(points), 4, T)) %>% 
            as.data.frame %>% 
            mutate(tot.dist = NA)

for(i in 1:nrow(paths)){
    d <- numeric(ncol(paths) - 2)
    for(j in 2:(ncol(paths) - 1)){
        d[j - 1] <- dists %>% 
                        filter(Var1 == paths[i, j - 1] & Var2 == paths[i, j]) %>% 
                        select(dist) %>% 
                        unlist
    }
    paths$tot.dist[i] <- sum(d)
}

paths

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5  tot.dist
# 1  c  c  e  e  c  99.29753
# 2  a  b  e  d  a 173.82135
# 3  d  e  e  d  a  87.30152
# 4  a  b  a  b  e 251.46679
```

Comment: This works but unfortunately does not scale well with very large datasets. Do you know if there is a way to modify this for speedup? I noticed that `a --> b` is looked up several times. Is there a way to only look it up once and fill in the matrix accordingly?

Comment: Row wise operations tend to be slow. I would try transposing and changing the loop indices accordingly